# needed method to accomplish this SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a way to define a variable to hold the result of an expression in MYSQL so that I can use that variable throughout the query.
So that this is possible:

```
SELECT 
IF(VALID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,"NULL") AS NAME,   /** <-- Note *VALID* 
IF(VALID,ID,"NULL") AS ID,   /** <-- And here... 
IF(VALID,OCCUPATION,"NULL") AS OCCUPATION,   /** <-- And here... 

IF((**LONG EXPRESSION**), TRUE, FALSE) AS VALID; /** <-- Taken from here
```

where LONG EXPRESSION can be very loong expression that I need to put for every returned Column in the IF statement, there are many IFs.

My instinct tells me that I should be able to do this like in every procedural language:

```
$var = LONG_EXPRESSION(....);
if($var) {..};
if($var) {..};
if($var) {..};
if($var) {..};
```

This way it is a lot more logical and less error prone. easily maintained, readable, perhaps even optimized.

Is there an equivalent for this inside MYSQL ?
Thus, defining a parameter for every single row of execution ?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? If it's valid, then you want a value or else NULL for each field in your result?

Comment: So you want to get `NAME, ID, OCCUPATION, ETC.` for all `VALID` entries in the result, in which some complex logic giving `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `VALID` is `TRUE`? Is that right? You're describing a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I need a zero or NULL, and values for where the result works. WHERE would simply NOT return the lines that VALUE is false for, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a subquery:

```
SELECT IF(VALID,EMPLOYEE_NAME,"NULL") AS NAME,   /** <-- Note *VALID* 
       IF(VALID,ID,"NULL") AS ID,   /** <-- And here... 
       IF(VALID,OCCUPATION,"NULL") AS OCCUPATION,
       ...,
       VALID
from (select t.*, IF((**LONG EXPRESSION**), TRUE, FALSE) AS VALID
      from t
    ) t
```

Comment: Will this work? What benefit is this over a `WHERE` clause even if it does? All the fields are `"NULL"` for any `inVALID` expression result, so...?

Comment: You should ask this to the person who wrote the question.  I can't justify what that person needs.

Comment: My first question was, "Will it work"; I'm skeptical `VALID` will even work in the field list as demonstrated. Aside: Just because someone suggests doing something does not mean it *should* be done that way, or that it works. I get the feeling there's some misunderstanding by the OP; I noted that in a comment already.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more appropriate way to do this is to do an `OUTER JOIN` between the original table and a subquery with a `WHERE` clause containing the long expression.

```
SELECT IF(b.rowid IS NULL, "NULL", a.employee_name) AS name,
       IF(b.rowid IS NULL, "NULL", a.id) AS id,
       IF(b.rowid IS NULL, "NULL", a.occupation) AS occupation,
       ...,
       IF(b.rowid IS NULL, 0, 1) AS valid
FROM mytable a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT rowid FROM mytable
 WHERE **LONG EXPRESSION**) b
ON a.rowid = b.rowid
```

This assumes `rowid` is a unique key column in the table.